# split comma separated string by comma

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to split the string containing country names separated by comma(,) and also **country name itself contains comma(,)** too.

```
var str = "South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands,Congo, Democratic Republic,Mauritania,Finland,Spain,Armenia,Mauritius,France,Sri Lanka,Aruba,Mayotte,French Guiana,Suriname,Australia,Mexico,French Polynesia,Svalbard and Jan Mayen,Austria,Micronesia, Federated States,French Southern Territories";
```

Expected result:

```
[   "South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands",
    "Mexico",
    "French Polynesia",
    "Congo, Democratic Republic",
    "Svalbard and Jan Mayen",
    "Micronesia, Federated States",
]
```

Comment: Your delimiter is not suitable because it is also contained in the values ("Congo, Democratic Republic", "Micronesia, Federated States"). You should change it to ';' or '§' or something else. After that you could use split() as pointed out by Hamza below.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you don't want to use a character that could show up in valid countries as the deliminator, aka `,` 
However if we can assume that `,` will only show up without spaces around it when its used as a deliminator. Then we could use a regex to split the string:

```js
var str = "South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands,Congo, Democratic Republic,Mauritania,Finland,Spain,Armenia,Mauritius,France,Sri Lanka,Aruba,Mayotte,French Guiana,Suriname,Australia,Mexico,French Polynesia,Svalbard and Jan Mayen,Austria,Micronesia, Federated States,French Southern Territories";
var res = str.split(/(?<=\w),(?=\w)/i);
console.log(res)
```

**Regex explained:**

- `(?<=\w)` is a look behind for any "word" character.
- `(?=\w)` is a look ahead for any "word" character.
- `,` will match a comma char if and only if the look ahead and look behind succeeds.

Interactive example: https://regexr.com/42b3e

**Edit:**

Efter looking into an issue brought up by @BorisSokolov in the comments, its become clear that the regex implementation differs between the major javascript runtimes.

Runtimes tested:

- [V8](https://github.com/v8/v8)(includes Node): Works as intended
- [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey): Throws 
  `SyntaxError: invalid regexp group`. Turns out Mozilla [haven't yet implemented](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225665) the "possitive look behind" standard.
- [ChakraCore](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore): Throws `Script error`. Same here, turns out microsoft haven't yet implemented the "positive look behind" standard either.

Looking at TC39 we can see that the ["possitive look behind" is part of the ES2018 spec](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind). So its expected to be implemented in all major browsers in the near future.

Comment: "message": "SyntaxError: invalid regexp group",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 14,
  "colno": 20

Comment: @BorisSokolov i don't know about that. It runs just fine for me.

Comment: Thank you so much @Olian04,
its working fine. If possible can you explain the regex?

Comment: @ManimaranM I've added an explanation and an interactive example. Feel free to accept the answer (click the checkmark) if you feel that it resolved your issue :)

Comment: @Olian04 the quotes were missing. Have updated your snippet

Comment: @BorisSokolov what browser are you using? Because the snippet in my answer is valid javascript. If you [run the code in node](https://repl.it/repls/NauticalHideousQuotient) instead you should see that it works as intended.

Comment: @Olian04 it works in Chrome and crashes in FF and Edge.

Comment: @BorisSokolov i did some testing and I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the string is in the same format as above then first you need to split string with comma.
if item in the result array begins with a space then merge that item with previous item in the result array.
In country names with comma, there exists a space after comma while others not

Answer (score -1):

There is probably a way to do it by regular expression, but I would suggest the easy way. Looking at your input, you can see that those commas that separate the title of a country from it's name are followed by a space, whereas the listing comma isn't followed by one:
`var str = "South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands,Congo, Democratic Republic,Mauritania,Finland,Spain,Armenia,Mauritius,France,Sri Lanka,Aruba,Mayotte,French Guiana,Suriname,Australia,Mexico,French Polynesia,Svalbard and Jan Mayen,Austria,Micronesia, Federated States,French Southern Territories";`

So in order to separate those two, I would suggest replacing `", "` by a special character that would not occur in your input - say `"$"`. Afterwards, you can split by `","`. Then you can replace your special character back to `", "`:

```
function getCountryList(str) {
  var strWithSpecialCharacterReplaced = str.replace(", ", "$");
  var countryList = strWithSpecialCharacterReplaced.split(",");
  return countryList.map(countryString => countryString.replace("$", ", "));
}
```

This is of course not the most performant solution. But it is one.

Answer (score -1):

Just use Regex!

```js
var str = "South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands,Congo, Democratic Republic,Mauritania,Finland,Spain,Armenia,Mauritius,France,Sri Lanka,Aruba,Mayotte,French Guiana,Suriname,Australia,Mexico,French Polynesia,Svalbard and Jan Mayen,Austria,Micronesia, Federated States,French Southern Territories";
var res = str.split(/(?<=\w),(?=\w)/i);
console.log(res)
```

In this example, I use (? = [A-zA-Z0-9]) [,] (? = [A-zA-Z0-9]) to get all the commas surrounded by letters and divide them (the " , "is not divided in this case and return is correct)! Tested and working!