# RegExp javascript, get words between colons but that are not enclosed by qoutes

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently this is my regex:

```
/(:)(.*?)(:)/g
```

Now I need you not to take the words that are in quotes

This Yes:

:dsadasd:

This No:

":dsadasd:"

Comment: Have you tried writing some JavaScript code yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: I do not understand your comment

Comment: Please give more examples of input and expected output. How is you input formatted, is it a line or part of a big string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
/(?!.*")(:)(.*?)(:)/g
```

It adds a `negative look ahead` that excludes lines with a `double quote`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use lookaheads and lookbehinds, like this: `(?<!")(?<=:)(\w*?)(?=:)(?!")`

Ex playground: https://regex101.com/r/OnCA3N/2/

```js
const regex = /(?<!")(?<=:)(\w*?)(?=:)(?!")/gm;
const str = `:sadasd: :hello:
":saddads:" ":hello:"`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    console.log(m[0]);
}
```

Comment: Javscript does not support look behind.

Comment: @PoulBak Yes it does. Its part of the ES2018 spec and is currently implemented in V8.

Comment: In theory, yes, but not implemented in browsers.

Comment: @PoulBak it is implemented in V8 (aka chrome & node) and it is going to be implemented in the other major runtimes. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53101201/6224823) for further reference.

Comment: Well, let's hope the OP has time to wait then.

Answer (score 0):

Better use negative lookarounds:

```
^(?<!")(:)(.*?)(:)(?!")$
```

Comment: Javscript does not support look behind.

Comment: JS that supports ECMAScript 2018 supports lookbehinds and even more, but this pattern does not really make sense as there cannot be a `"` before the start and end of string.

Comment: Well if the words are inline this regex could work: (?<= :)(.+?)(?=: )